# How to hide a specific column in a virtual string tree?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

How can I hide specific columns in my virtual string tree?

I've tried this code:

```
Header.Columns.Items[3].Width := -1;
```

It displays the column, but not the header caption. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To hide a column, eliminate coVisible from the TVTColumnOption enumeration, e.g.,

```
if coVisible in VST.Header.Columns[3].Options then
  VST.Header.Columns[3].Options := VST.Header.Columns[3].Options - [coVisible];
```

The TVirtualTreeColumn class has a MinWidth property that would override any column width less than MinWidth. I'm not in a position right now to check this, but I don't think MinWidth will even accept a negative integer value.